# Heroku + Logs Command :: Can Logs Detail can be increased at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, heroku

Is it possible to see the last log of Heroku server. I have used `heroku logs` to see the last process but it shows limited log. But i want to see more process done at heroku. So what command or what process should I follow to see the logs at Heroku.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LogWorm add-on to push all of your log into this service : http://addons.heroku.com/logworm

Comment: Thanks buddy, Ya its fine, but my client is not going to give me such permission for this. Please suggest me some alternate option if you can.

Comment: This is a valid answer. You did not mention anything about client/permission in your question. Please accept this or another answer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's possible because on Heroku's own support page they recommend using external monitoring applications. They have likely limited it to 100 lines to prevent people from using it as their only debugging tool.

http://docs.heroku.com/logs-exceptions

> Accessing your logs is intended
>   primarily for use in debugging a newly
>   uploaded application that is producing
>   unexpected results, such as an
>   exception or a 500 / FAILSAFE error.
>   The logs displayed will be a jumble of
>   results from the different servers
>   your app happens to be running on, and
>   will show only the most recent 100
>   lines.
>
> If you have a site in production use
>   by real users, use an external
>   exception logging service. We can
>   recommend Hoptoad and Get Exceptional.
>   Both of these services are very simple
>   to set up on Heroku, and provide an
>   easy and structured way to look at all
>   your production exceptions.
>
> You should not attempt to use the
>   output of the heroku logs command for
>   metrics or usage analysis. For that,
>   we recommend Google Analytics.

Alternative exception monitoring applications:

- Exceptional (http://www.getexceptional.com/)
- Airbrake (ex Hoptoadapp) (http://airbrake.io/pages/home)

There are also a few projects on Github that allow you to build an exception logging system into your application:

- Exception Notifier (http://github.com/rails/exception_notification)
- Exception Logger (http://github.com/defunkt/exception_logger)
- Tartus (http://github.com/dinsley/tartarus)

Here are a couple of Railscasts tutorials by Ryan Bates on the topic:

- Exception Notifications (http://railscasts.com/episodes/104-exception-notifications)
- Handling Exceptions (http://railscasts.com/episodes/53-handling-exceptions)

I have just checked and the first suggestion, Exceptional, is actually available as an official Heroku add-on.

- http://addons.heroku.com/exceptional

as is Hoptoadapp.

- http://addons.heroku.com/hoptoad

Comment: Please suggest me some alternate option if you can. With-out disturbing heroku settings.

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked this question, Heroku has released more robust logging:

http://docs.heroku.com/logging

There's a realtime tail and filtering options.

Answer (score 1):

```
heroku logs -n 1000
```

to see 1000 logs lines you can change the no of lines

```
heroku logs -t
```

to see live logs

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Specific logger to save all log in your Database.